# Bluemix, Watson, speech to text - tone analysis

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

would like to know if Bluemix, potentially Watson capability could do the following:  if multiple persons having conversation via one or many microphones as streamed audio source, could identify also a person tone / spectrum - i.e. who of all is producing the sound ?Thanks: Markku

Comment: The best place for questions about the capabilities of Bluemix services is IBM developerWorks Answers - https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html. Stack Overflow is best for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Watson API to work on an audio stream at the moment.
As you pointed out, you could use Speech-to-text to get a transcript of the conversation and potentially Tone-analyzer to get a sentiment analysis but this won't be enough to determine who's the speaker.

If you want to know more about how those two services work, please check their pages on the [Watson Developer Cloud](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/services-catalog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example application and the code for combining STT and Tone Analyzer:

Application

https://realtime-tone.mybluemix.net/

Get the code here to use for your own applications:

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/real-time-tone-analysis

Julia